# Deciding the matrix for a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been going through a bunch of questions, but i'm stuck on one and I can't wrap my head around how to solve it or beging solving it in the first place, so I need some help.
The question is:
Decide the matrix for a linear transformation $F$ in the space that is defined by $u$ projecting on the intersection between the plane $x + y + z = 0$ and the plane $x + z = 0$, and then reflected in the plane $x-y-z = 0.$

Excuse me if I have made any mistakes, I am not a native English speaker.

Thank you.

Comment: I suppose that $F$ is a linear map from $\mathbb{R}^3$ into itself. Am I right?

Comment: Yes I suppose so !

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Nothing, I don't know where to begin.

Comment: Can you find the matrix of the linear transformation for the projection or reflection separately? If so you can multiply them together in the correct order to get the desired matrix.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Not sure if I follow what you mean.
Could you elaborate further?

Comment: If $A$ is the desired projection matrix and $B$ is the desired reflection matrix then $B(Au)=(BA)u$ so $BA$ is the desired linear transformation.